# how to increase the size of UIButtonTypeInfoLight

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, bounds

i have tried the below code , but size of button is remains same

```
UIButton * pInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

[pInfoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 80, 80)];

[pInfoButton setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];

[self.view addSubview:pInfoButton];
```

please tell me how to increase it's size , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase it applying CGAffineTransform to the button: `pInfoButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);`. But in this case you'll lose a quality.

Another solution is to create custom button with background.

Answer (score 2):

use the UIButtonTypeCustom and set the image of the button as that of the info.

```
UIButton*infoButton=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
infoButton.frame=CGRectMake(100,100, 80, 80); 
[infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:infoButton];
```

Comment: it's a custom button ,it's a alternative way to achieve this , but my question is different . but thanks for reply

Comment: you can make a custom button to look alike an info button

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked fine for me, [image: Check attached image]

Here You have use   m_pInfoButton to add button [self.view addSubview:m_pInfoButton], replace code with    [self.view addSubview:pInfoButton].

```
UIButton * pInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[pInfoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 80, 80)];
[pInfoButton setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[self.view addSubview:pInfoButton];
```

Comment: i have corrected the question . . . i have changed m_pInfoButton to pInfoButton , but still no luck

Comment: Check my edited comment, 
Try to set background color like pInfoButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor], and check button is there or not.

Comment: can we increase the size of info symbol ? Bcoz in above case frame is increasing but not the symbol .

Comment: No that's not possible using type UIButtonTypeInfoLight, you can get it by implementing UIButtonTypeCustom and by setting image for info.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do change the size of `Information Button`, just create a custom UIButton with information icon to replace it.